# Ext JS rest proxy has error while saving an instance of model

Tags: rest, extjs, model, proxy

i just try some example from http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest.Here the code:

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'name', 'email'],

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url : '/users'
    }
});

var user = Ext.create('User', {name: 'Ed Spencer', email: 'ed@sencha.com'});

user.save(); //POST /users
```

when I create a new User instance and call save method, I get this error:

Uncaught Unable to parse the JSON returned by the server: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String:

here the complete error warning from chrome web developer console:

```
Uncaught Unable to parse the JSON returned by the server: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /users</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /users</h1>
<table><tr><th><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="[ICO]"></th><th><a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a></th><th><a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a></th><th><a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a></th><th><a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a></th></tr><tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="/">Parent Directory</a>       </td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
</table>
<address>Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Comment: can you post the JSON that is being sent to your server?

Comment: I think iamkrillin meant the JSON sent back *from* the server.

Comment: @Dani Petrick, how did you realize the server method? What does it return? Look at 'Network' tab in Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: @Alexey Solonets: I see POST method and I can not see what doest it's return. I really don't have idea about this problem. Help me please...

Comment: Your problem is that you did not implement any handler for the `/users` URL. So Apache gives you index of your catalog.

Comment: @Alexey Solonots: how to implement it's handler?

Comment: This sounds like 'how to program?'... Sorry this question is already not about ExtJS

Comment: @Alexey Solonets: I don't mean 'how to program'. I will find where i can implement it's handler. Thank you :)